# GIS Maximum area coverage problem

Tags: qgis, analysis, sextante

I want to find optimum antenna location for an area. Every antenna can cover an circular area. These areas diameter is 750meter. So how can i find minimum number of antennas and locations.
**NOTE: I use QGIS. Blank areas are not important. Only buildings must be covered.**

To better understand here is example images...

Here is building layer [image]

Firstly i generated 50m grid of the layer.[image]

After that i intersected it with building layer. So i can eliminate blank areas. [image]

I stucked in here. Which tool can help me determine location of  antennas (750meter diameter). I know it can not show me %100 optimum locations. Bu i need possible locations. Here is another screen that i made it myself without analysis tools. The result must look like that. Thanks anyway.
[image]

Comment: Can you explain your idea behind creating a grid? Do all buildings have to get coverage or only a certain percentage?

Comment: This sounds like a Multi-criteria analysis problem.  Probably best suited to raster data.